# WITH is like a temp table or is just an alias

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, query-performance

I have an `UNION ALL` query and both queries have a lot in common. I am using `WITH` to work with the common part (the difference is that the first makes a join with one table and the second query joins to another - and I need a union of the results).

My questions are:

- Is there difference in performance using `WITH` (just like a temp table)?
- The `WITH` is just an alias and it will be calculated twice?
- The SQL Server is smart enough to perceive there are a lot of common in two queries and it will make no difference using `WITH` or not?
- It would be better if instead of `WITH` I have used a table valued function or a view?

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of how common table expressions (CTE) relate to temporary tables on DB2.  CTE is created with the WITH keyword.

When you use a CTE is may not be fully materialized when the select runs.  DB2 is free to optimize what part of the table is materialized in order to run the query.

I have found that temporary tables are usually faster.  I suspect this is because I can add indexes on the temporary table.  This also reduces the size of the final query so the optimizer has an easier time finding a good execution path.

I will use CTE if I am a bit lazy and don't want to create a temporary table or if I want to take advantage of the fact that it does not materialize the entire table.

When I use temp table I am careful to add qualifiers in so that I am not building a table that is larger than necessary.